# Non-blocking data sharing through OpenMPI

Tags: c++, c, parallel-processing, mpi, openmpi

I'm trying to spread data across multiple workers using OpenMPI, however, I'm doing the data division in a fairly custom way that is *not* amenable to `MPI_Scatter` or `MPI_Broadcast`. What I would like to do is to give each processor some work in a queue (or, some other async mechanism) such that they can do their work on the first chunk of data, take the next chunk, repeat until no more chunks.

I know of `MPI_Isend`, however if I send data with `MPI_Isend` I can't modify it until it's finished sending; forcing me to use `MPI_Wait` and thus having to wait until the thread is finished receiving the data anyway!

Is there a standard a solution to this problem, or must I rethink my approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `MPI_ISEND` doesn't necessarily mean that the message is received on the remote end. It just means that the buffer is available for reuse. It could be that the message has been buffered internally by Open MPI or that the message actually has been received on the other end. It depends on your message size.

Another option would be to have your workers ask the master process for work when they need it instead of having it pushed to them. Then the master can work only as needed. You could do an `MPI_SCATTER` for the first message since everyone will be receiving some data. Then after that, have the master do an `MPI_RECV(MPI_ANY_SOURCE)` to get a message from one of the worker processes.

Comment: Oh, okay, so `WAIT`ing on an `ISEND` will return once the data is buffered internally, rather than waiting until the client has received the data? This may be what I want then, since this should implicitly queue data.

The `MPI_RECV(MPI_ANY_SOURCE)` idea is good, but it would relegate master to only data splitting rather than collating the results of currently-completed operations, wouldn't it?

Comment: Nope. You can use multiple tags in your 'MPI_IRECV' to separate out the kind of messages. If you have a message asking for work, you can respond accordingly. If you have a message replying with the results, you can receive the data and keep going. Just use either two `MPI_IRECV` calls with an `MPI_WAITANY` or you could combine them and just have the master automatically send back work after receiving results.

Comment: Fantastic, this sounds like what I wanted. Thanks for the help!